# ESLint warning in camelcase for locale code

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint

I use ESLint for improving my code quality but I need it not warning some declaration such as locale code `en_US`.

[ESLint warning for camelcase rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2R0D.png)

If I add some configuration in comment just like [the document](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/camelcase#never) told

```
/* eslint camelcase: ["error", "properties": ["never"]] */
import zh_TW from 'moment/locale/zh-tw';
```

ESLint still warning the camelcase issue. How can I turn the warning off in this case?

Comment: Have you can tried 
    import { zh_TW **as zhTw** } from 'moment/locale/zh-tw';

Comment: I can use `import zhTW from 'moment/locale/zh-tw'` for correcting the warning. But I don't know which is the common one, `enUS` or `en_US` since `en-US` cannot be use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a doubt about the configuration line:

```
Doc says:
/* eslint camelcase: ["error", {properties: "never"}] */
But you did this:
/* eslint camelcase: ["error", "properties": ["never"]] */
```

( Edit: Buuut it does not seem to make a difference (see comments). Problem must be somewhere else )

Also I'm not sure you got @vahdet's suggestion:

```
import { zh_TW as zhTw } from 'moment/locale/zh-tw';
               ^^^^^^^
```

Then you use `zhTw` in your code instead of `zh_TW`, and no need for an exclusion for the linter :)

Comment: Oh, there is a typo, thanks! I got you, sorry about the comment above, I misunderstood what you guys said, `import { zh_TW as zhTW } from 'moment/locale/zh-tw';` definitely works but it is same to `import zhTW from 'moment/locale/zh-tw`. I have to accurate my question to ask which one is common use - `zhTW` or `zh_TW`.

Comment: I see. To answer that question I think the most common form is `zh_TW`, `zh_CN`, `en_US`, `fr_FR`, `fr_CA`, etc. But that's just my impression. But also my impression is that the name of the variable does not matter (apart from the linter's point of view...), does it?

Comment: Update: Sorry, I tried correct my typo, eslint still showing the warning.

Comment: You're right, just little bit OCD force me to know which one is better.

Comment: Ah OK, sorry I did not try myself, it's just that you linked the doc and it said something different :) I understand avoiding the issue with `as zhTW` is not satisfactory, and it'd be nice to feel in control of the linter... Updated the answer just to let it known the first suggestion does not work.